# How to load my Keras model from a group in HDF5 file using Python

Tags: python, keras, hdf5

I need to save some other attributes with my model into an HDF5 file. So I saved it in the following way, where `model` is a Keras model from a deep learning project. Now, I want to read this model into Keras using `load_model()` from Keras. How can I do it? I have tried to copy `root_item = h5file.get('model/kerasmodel')` into another HDF5 as a root, but it doesn't work.

```
def save_nn_model(h5file_name, model, encoder):
    with h5py.File(h5file_name,'w') as h5file:
        h5file.create_group('encoder')
        h5file['encoder'].attrs['name'] = encoder.name()
        h5file['encoder'].attrs['board_width'] = encoder.board_width
        h5file['encoder'].attrs['board_height'] = encoder.board_height
        h5file.create_group('model')
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
            model.save(f.name, save_format='h5')
            serialized_model = h5py.File(f.name, 'r')
            root_item = serialized_model.get('/')
            serialized_model.copy(root_item, h5file['model'], 'kerasmodel')
```

Here are the error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/Python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-e38ef1020b2c>", line 1, in <module>
    load_model('test.h5')
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/Python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/Python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 175, in load_model_from_hdf5
    raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
ValueError: No model found in config file.
```

Comment: Save the model by ```model.save('model.h5')```. Then load the model using ```from keras.models import load_model```  ```model = load_model('model.h5')```

Comment: I knew this way, but I have to save many other stuff in the same HDF5 file as above. So is there anyway that I can unpack the model from my saved HDF5 file?